# format text using a string

Tags: php, string, format

I am want to format a text from using a string as the formatter. Something like this:

`echo formatText('5555555555','(ddd) ddd-dddd');`

which will give me result

`(555) 555-5555`

How can I achieve that?

Thanks,
Gasim

Comment: Check the function [`money_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

Comment: Sounds like a good practice using money_format() to format a telephone number! :D

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) I think it's what you're looking for

```
echo sprintf("(%d) %d-%d",$prefix, $first-part, $second-part);
```

or

```
printf("(%d) %d-%d",$prefix, $first-part, $second-part);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to match valid input and format it as desired:

```
echo preg_replace('/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', '($1) $2-$3', '5556667777');
```